# search and replace multiple numbers in a file

Tags: perl

I am trying to do inline search and replace in a file using Perl 5.10.1

When i search for say a number like 73.10 and replace it with 73.20. It finds 73100.25 and replaces it with 73.200.25 and 73.10 with 73.20.

the file has 6 columns that appear like the below:

text  text  text  73100.25  25.12  text

text  text  text  365.8     96.25  text

text  text  text  23189.73  73.10  text

how do i ensure that it does not replace the wrong number?

```
`/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e "s/$num1/$num3/g" new_info.txt`;
`/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e "s/$num2/$num4/g" new_info.txt`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -i -pe 's/\Q$num1\E/$num3/g' new_info.txt
```

Comment: Thanks!! I had to remove "\b" and "(?=\s)" to get it to work.